# Adding Calendar Event from WebView

Tags: android, webview, calendar

I am following [this tutorial](https://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/creating-calendar-events-using-webview-in-android/) to made adding of calendar event from `WebView` possible. I understand that the method is using `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` for url `date:`.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

if (url.startsWith("date:")) {

Log.d(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),url);

Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();

Date beginDate = new Date(0, 0, 0);

Date endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0);

String parsed = url.substring(5);

String[] components = parsed.split(",");

beginDate.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(components[0]));

beginDate.setDate(Integer.parseInt(components[1]));

beginDate.setYear(Integer.parseInt(components[2]));

beginCal.setTime(beginDate);

endDate.setMonth(Integer.parseInt(components[3]));

endDate.setDate(Integer.parseInt(components[4]));

endDate.setYear(Integer.parseInt(components[5]));

endCal.setTime(endDate);

calendarevent(beginCal, endCal, components[6]);

return true;

}

return false;

}

});
```

However, I can't understand the format of `date:` url which I should put:

```
<a href='date:beginmonth, beginday, beginyear, 
endmonth, endday, endyear, My Event Description'>
My event link</a>
```

For example, I have an event on 15 September 2016, so I made the url become:

```
<a href='date:09,15,2016,09,15,2016, My Event Description'>
    My event link</a>
```

I got the wrong date. The date become 11 May 2011. What the mistake I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem myself. The bug occurs probably due to usage of deprecated `Date` as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html). Changed to `Calendar.set` and it's work now.

```
Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();

String parsed = url.substring(5);
String[] components = parsed.split(",");
int month = Integer.parseInt(components[0])-1;
int day = Integer.parseInt(components[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(components[2]);
beginCal.set(year, month, day);

int monthend = Integer.parseInt(components[3])-1;
int dayend = Integer.parseInt(components[4]);
int yearend = Integer.parseInt(components[5]);

endCal.set(yearend, monthend, dayend);
calendarevent(beginCal, endCal, components[6]);
```